# Python: Accessing class instance's `self` in decorator

Tags: python, class, reference, decorator

I have this decorator which takes one argument by itself before it decorates a provided function.

That decorator is then used to decorate a class method. Let's say we have the following code:

```
from somewhere import dec

class Something:
    def __init__(self, variable = 5):
        self.variable = variable

    @dec(need_to_access_instance_self_variable)
    def some_method(self, blahblah):
        # does something
        pass
```

Everything works like a charm, except I'd like to pass `self.variable` as an argument to the decorator—and nothing hasn't worked for me so far.

Is this even possible? I cannot seem to figure out the scoping. Any ideas how would that be achievable?

Thank you!

Comment: `self` does not exist there, so that isn't workable. Your decorator implementation can make use of the first-argument passed to the function it is decorating, maybe

Comment: `self` is a reference to the instance the method is being called on. At decoration time, there is no instance and therefore no `self`.

Comment: Note, `self` in Python is *way* more straight-forward than `this` in java-script, it is simply the first argument passed to the method, and when a method is accessed by an instance, it will auto-magically (through descriptors) be provided the instance accessing the method as the first argument. Indeed, it isn't the name `self` that has any special status, that is merely a convention, you *could* use `this` or `that` or `banana`, but what is important is that it is the *first* argument to a method.

Comment: IOW, you could think of `my_instance.some_method(arg1, arg2)` as being syntactic-sugar for `MyClass.my_method(my_instance, arg1, arg2)`

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga Yeah, accessing it from within decorated at runtime is a good idea :) Thank you